# I get Laravel Error "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list'

Tags: laravel, eloquent, mass-assignment

I make a controller function to insert new records on the quizzes table. To do that, I used Laravel mass assignment, and after that, I got this error message.

> "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'updated_at' in 'field list' (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into
> `quizzes` (`title`, `isfree`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values
> (Menjaga Pola Makan, 1, 2024-01-13 06:20:07, 2024-01-13 06:20:07))",
> "exception": "Illuminate\Database\QueryException",
> "file": "D:\laravel\Quiz-Health-Education\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php",
> "line": 822

**Controller**

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title'=>'required',
        'isfree'=>'required|boolean',
        'img'=>'string|nullable',
        'price'=>'nullable',
        'disc'=>'nullable'
    ]);

    if($request->isfree === false)
    {
        $request['price'] = null;
        $request['disc'] = null;
    }

    $request['created_at'] = $request->date('d-m-Y');

    Quiz::create($request->all());

    return response()->json(['status' => 'success']);
}
```

Comment: It can't find the updated_at column in your quizzes table. Does it exist?

Answer (score 0):

Check if  the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns is created. If not, create a new migration to add these columns.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration {
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('quizzes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
};
```

Additionally, you are manually defining the `created_at` value. It's not a good practice.
The column will automatically generate the value when `Quiz` is created (using the date and time of creation moment).

If there is a user-inserted value that needs to be stored, it is advisable to create a dedicated column for that input.

Comment: What will happen to the table if I remigrate. Will the records in the entire table disappear?

Comment: If you create a new migration and run `php artisan migrate`, the table will **not disappear**. If you use `php artisan migrate:fresh` **ALL TE RECORDS WILL DISAPPEAR**. The second one will drop all the records, tables, and run everything again. Just using `migrate`, only the new ones migrations will be executed.